# access intersection point of between a curve graph and a line

Tags: c#

i have a curve chart and one line.i wanna gain their intersection point.
i wrote below code. i compare points of two series to calculate intersection point. but it dose not work.

```
foreach (DataPoint series in chart.Series["T1"].Points)
        {
            foreach (DataPoint item in chart.Series["T2"].Points)
            {

                for (int j = 1; j < series.YValues.Length; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i < item.YValues.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (series.YValues == item.YValues)
                        {
                            //some code
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq

```
var intersectionPoints = chart.Series["T1"].Points.Intersect(chart.Series["T2"].Points);
```

Comment: i dont know . What to do?

Comment: My bad, You need to override `DataPoint`'s `Equals` method so `Intersect` will know how to compare between 2 DataPoints (The default comparison is by reference only)